# Python AES key value greater than 128

Tags: python, aes

I used the following example to use AES with python: [AES criptography](https://gist.github.com/gustavohenrique/79cc95cc351d975a075f18a5c9f49319). I modified the key to something like that:

```
key='\x61\x62\x53\x54\x55\x66\x67\x68\x69\x70\x71\x32\x33\x74\x75\x76'
```

This works fine. Note that all these hex-values are less than 128 and so they can represented within the ascii-table. When i change one value to `\x80` or higher i got this error message:

```
ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long
```

On my embedded device (in c) i can use a value greater than 128.

Comment: Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I use python 3.5

Comment: Then key should be binary data, write `key = b'\x61\x62`...

Comment: Thats it. Thanks!